# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple while trying to make 2D list

Tags: python, list, typeerror

I am trying to make a 2D list for a group of members/volunteers:

```
memberlist = [
['Cliff Burton', 'yes', 'pier', '05/09/1984', True]
['Lemmy Kilmister', 'no', 'none', '21/06/2001', False]
['Chris Cornell', 'yes', 'gift shop', '18/12/2005', True]
['Layne Staley', 'yes', 'pd', '28/09/1994', True]
['Ozzy Osbourne', 'yes', 'pd', '16/11/1971', False]
['Krist Novoselic', 'yes', 'pier', '23/01/1996', True]
['Paul Baloff', 'no', 'none', '05/08/1988', False]
]
```

*The 1st value is name, 2nd value whether they want to volunteer, 3rd where they want to volunteer, 4th date of joining, and 5th whether they have paid for membership* (but that's not very important).

What I get for the 2nd line (the one with Cliff Burton) is this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Why could this be?

Comment: Because you forgot a bunch of commas.

Comment: Thanks! It's a bit embarrassing really.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to add commas after each element.

If I flatten your code down onto one line and only look at the first two elements, you should see the issue.

```py
memberlist = [['Cliff Burton', 'yes', 'pier', '05/09/1984', True]['Lemmy Kilmister', 'no', 'none', '21/06/2001', False]]
```

Instead you should have:

```py
memberlist = [['Cliff Burton', 'yes', 'pier', '05/09/1984', True],['Lemmy Kilmister', 'no', 'none', '21/06/2001', False]]
```